# Fire QraphQl subscription resolver multiple times per single change

Tags: angular, graphql, graphql-subscriptions

Working with GraphQl subscriptions I`m facing a curious issue.
For purpose of real-time updates, I use MongoDB [Change Stream](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) feature on a server (NodeJs) and GraphQl subscriptions for front-end (Angular). So, when some changes appear in database its send to a client-side by GraphQl subscriptions.
On the Angular component, there is the GraphQl subscription implementation (use [Apollo client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/subscriptions.html)):

```
...
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribeToApprovedNews(this.params);
}

subscribeToApprovedNews(params) {
  this.newsQuery.subscribeToMore({
      document: addApprovedNews,
      variables: {
        projectId: params
      },
      updateQuery: (previous, { subscriptionData }) => {
        ...
        const newItem = subscriptionData.data['addApprovedNews'];
        console.log(`${params} -> added news -> ${newItem}`);
        ...
      }
  });
}
```

But when we enter to this component **n** times, on **one change in database** we receive data from subscription this **n** times.
As I understand when we entering the component the client has established new WebSocket connection:
["Network" tab of the Chrome developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cll4Z.png)
As transport for GraphQL subscriptions I use [subscriptions-transport-ws](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws/) package.

So, **one change on database** fire multiple QraphQl subscription resolvers and as a result on client-side we receive duplicated notification about change. 
How it`s possible to fix this behaviour and *to recieve only one data per subscription no matter how many times the user enters to the component*?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should unsubscribe when you leave component. Good place is ngOnDestroy method.

Comment: You`re right! By the way, this [resource](https://github.com/apollographql/react-docs/commit/25275368c8ae3c6b3dd9c20d9e362e3066ceaea6#diff-5da460d0858b1a81a0923cb6fcaaec09R112) describes how to implement unsubscribe method for _subscribeToMore_. Thanks!